# Django FileField not respecting null=False parameter

Tags: python, django

I have a Django FileField which is set to not nullable. However it is behaving like it is nullable.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)
    thing_id = models.CharField()  


# This does not raise but I would like it to
Thing.objects.create(thing_id='123')
```

edit: the migrations

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('data_source', '0002_auto_20190212_1913'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Thing',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('document', models.FileField(upload_to='')),
                ('thing_id', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=200)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: How does your form look like? are you overwritting the settings there?

Comment: There is no form, this is a direct ORM call @ohlr

Comment: What happens when you save that object into a variable and then manually run validation with `created_thing.full_clean()`?

Comment: @malberts ` django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'document': ['This field cannot be blank.']}`

Comment: what version of django are you running?

Comment: Django version 2.2b1

Comment: it behaves the same with 2.1.7

Comment: @NotHilaryClinton I believe you are running into the [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) behavior where a `.save()` (which happens inside `.create()`) does not perform full validation. Since you're not using a ModelForm, you have to do it yourself. So it's not that you have a problem with your Model (as shown by the fact that you got the validation error when running `full_clean()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your field definition. It's got to do with validation when manually creating a model instance. You need to perform that full validation yourself, since you're not using a ModelForm.

Use this example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

thing = Thing(thing_id='123')

try:
    thing.full_clean()
    thing.save()
except ValidationError:
    # Handle validation issues.
```

Read this section in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Quoting from there:

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call
>   your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you
>   want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created
>   models

Comment: This field should be validated at the db level not here.

Comment: @NotHilaryClinton I'm trying to find an official explanation, but I'm coming up short. So here's how I understand it. `blank` is non-database level and `null` is database level ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank)). But an empty FileField doesn't actually store `NULL` in the database, it stores a blank string, similar to a CharField (see this [warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) on using `null` with those). So *technically*, your field passes the db validation (because "" != NULL)  and you have to check non-db yourself.

Comment: @NotHilaryClinton It's similar to how you can manually `.save()` a model instance without a value for a required CharField. It also won't trigger any database constraint violations.

Answer (score 0):

By default `null` and `blank` are `False`. [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#null) for every model field. Don't need to add those.

```
from django.db import models
class Thing(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField()
    thing_id = models.CharField()
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem I am having.

Comment: can you please add `Thing` table's create migratetions.py.

Comment: btw what is your `BaseModel` can you please add defination of that model too.

Comment: added migrations, and ignore basemodel its just adding some fields

Comment: do you catching your exception anywhere, or extend validation-error catching else or add `try - except` block ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the validation directly in your model overriding `save()` method:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    thing_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```